# Deleting the smallest element in a binary tree

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, binary-tree, min

How would one go about to delete the smallest element in a binary tree? I know how to delete when they ask you to delete a certain element, but I'm just really stumped on this one. Here is the code for deleting a specific value in a tree.

```
def delete(tree):
    if tree == None:
        return None
    else:
        if tree['left']['left'] == None:
            tree['left'] = None
         #this is where I get stuck
```

Comment: What have you tried? What part are you having problems with? Can you find the smallest element? Do you know how to traverse all the elements of a binary tree?

Comment: @timgeb I tried traversing through the left side, but I'm having trouble actually deleting the node, Cause with a value, I can actually say 'hey, while going down the tree, find this element and delete it' I tried making it so it would traverse through the left left side of the tree and find a leaf and delete it, but it didnt work

Comment: first, the code is not syntactically correct. Second, comments around your first else are incorrect justifications about the structure of the tree when the preceding conditions are false.

Comment: @Qman485 It sounds like the approach you stated in your comment was headed in the right direction. Could you put up your code for that? In what way did it not work?

Comment: @kjschiroo I have updated the code, Im just having trouble understanding the whole figuring out how to go all the way to last left leaf

Comment: use recursive. Keep finding the left node and remove its reference in the parent node if no more left node can be found

Comment: Do you _know_ the tree to be a search tree/ordered? When you know `if tree['left']['left'] == None:`, what about `tree['left']['right']`?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [the heapq implementation provided in the Python standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html), to directly accomplish the task of removing the minimum value from a binary tree, then studying [the source code of the heapq module](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/heapq.py) to understand how the algorithm is implemented.

```
import heapq
from random import seed, randint

seed(0)
items = [randint(1,100) for i in range(10)]
# [85, 76, 43, 26, 52, 41, 79, 31, 48, 59]

# create the heap queue / priority queue
h = []
for i in items:
    heapq.heappush(h, i)

# the smallest item
heapq.heappop(h)
# 26
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you just forgot to include the recursive step. I've included it in the code below.

```
def delete(tree):
    if tree == None:
        return None
    else:
        if tree['left']['left'] == None:
            tree['left'] = tree['left']['right'] # I also changed this
        else:
            delete(tree['left']) # recursive part
```

In the event that `tree['left']['left'] != None` you know the smallest value is somewhere farther down the left side of the tree, so just call `delete()` again on that side until we find a node where `tree['left']['left'] == None`.